# VS code does not display index date on the table while clicking on variable

Tags: python, date, visual-studio-code, indexing

I have a dataframe in which the index is date of the format Day/Month/year. When I print the dataframe, the index date is there. However, when I go to variables and open the dataframe, the index is not displayed. Instead, there is an empty cell. I have taken the same code/dataframe into Pycharm and this problem does not occur. I have uploaded the screenshots of the problem.

Any idea why it happens and how to solve?
[image: DF printed]

[image: displaying variable(df)]

Comment: file a bug in the VSCode repo (github)

Answer (score -1):

I think this is a vscode bug. I have submitted it to GitHub for you